One layer of Detection Transformer (DETR) decoder and self attention layer
The key purpose of the self-attention layer in the DETR decoder is to aggregate information between object queries.
However, if the decoder has only one layer, would it still be necessary to have a self-attention layer?
At the beginning of the training, object queries are initialized with random values through nn.Embedding. Since there is only one decoder layer, it only shares these unnecessary random values among the queries, performs cross-attention, predicts the result, and completes the forward process (as there is only one decoder layer).
Therefore, if there is only one decoder layer, it seems that the self-attention layer is quite useless.
Is there any other purpose for the self-attention layer that I might need to understand?
